# percents off and discounts

Tags: arithmetic

How do you do this question:  Employees of a discount appliance store recieve an additional 20% off of the lowest price on an item. If an employee purchases a dishwasher during a 15% off sale, how much will he pay if the dishwasher originally cost $450?

Answer (score 2):

First take off 15%.

$(1 - .15)(450) = (.85)(450)$ dollars.

Then take off 20%.

$(1 - .20)(.85)(450) = (.8)(.85)(450)$ dollars.

This is the amount that an employee pays.